# C(++) and Lua Cleaning up Memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, lua

I am using Lua's C API in an application I'm writing, and I'm trying to determine if the way I'm using it is leaving some dangling pointers (to pointers).

Say I have a tree like structure (class actually) in C++

```
struct Leaf
{
  DoSomeLeafStuff();
  List<Leaf*> Children;
};

class Tree
{
public:
  Tree() { };
  virtual ~Tree() 
  { 
    /* iterate over Children and delete them */ 
  };

  void DoSomeTreeStuff();
  Leaf getRoot() const { return _root; }

private:
  Leaf* _root;
};
```

-- Assume `tree` was already created and contains data and I use it like this in Lua:

```
local root = tree:getRoot()
root:DoSomeLeafStuff()
```

Now my C implementation of `getRoot()` for Lua looks something like:

```
int LuaStuff::TreeGetRoot(lua_State* L)
{
  Tree* tree = *(Tree**)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "MyStuff.Tree");

  if (tree != NULL && tree->getRoot() != NULL)
  {
    int size = sizeof(Leaf**);
    *((Leaf**)lua_newuserdata(L, size)) = tree->getRoot(); // allocate a pointer to a pointer
    lua_setmetatable(L, "MyStuff.Leaf");
  }
  else
  {
    lua_pushnil(L);
  }

  return 1;
}
```

After some troubleshooting, I was able to get my Tree and Leaf objects to free up when you'd expect. But so far I haven't found a convincing way (to me at least) that the pointer-pointers are getting cleaned up.

My question is: can I safely assume that memory allocated by Lua's lua_newuserdata() gets cleaned up automatically by Lua's garbage collection?

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/GarbageCollectionTutorial

Answer (score 1):

I was doing similar thing wrapping my own objects in Lua. That's how I do that:

```
/*part of the functon, buffer_s is a structure holding pointer 
to the real object and some other fields (like who actually created the object)
*/
buffer_s* b = (buffer_s*) lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(buffer_s));
b->ptr = new buffer;        
b->origin = FROM_LUA;       
luaL_getmetatable(L, "buffer");
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
```

Now, while initing library I also do something like this:

```
luaL_newmetatable(L, "buffer");  //create metatable
lua_pushcfunction(L,lua_buffer_delete); //push Lua compatible "destructor"
lua_setfield(L, -2, "__gc");    //place it in the metatable under __gc index

lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");

luaL_register(L, NULL, maps_buffer_m);
```

Now Lua will call the __gc metamethod before free()ing (by GC) the object. You can use it to do the clean-up.

I do it like this (part of the function):

```
if (b->origin == FROM_LUA)
{

     delete b->ptr;   //delete the object
     b->origin = PTR_INVALID;  //and mark it as invalid
     b->ptr = NULL;
     lua_newtable(L);
     lua_setmetatable(L, 1);        //set empty metatable, it's not buffer any more
     return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps :)

You could think about using tolua++ or swig to automate the process of doing the binding. It will save lots of time and will probably take care of object creation and deletion in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend you to use some [Lua Wrapper Class](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CppConvenientLuaWrapperClass). I've been using it in our project, and it works verry good. It also makes things a lot easier.
With this class when your Lua Script ends, the wrapper destroys your Lua State that was beeing used freeing your memory, and all your user Data.

I also think that if you do something like:

```
lua_close( mState );
```

Your userData will also be cleaned.